# bitcoind removed from version 0.12?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, nodes

I just updated my node to the lastest version 0.12, it launched and synced up fine.  Afterwards I closed the core GUI and launched bitcoind through the command line `bitcoind -server` and it returned with "Access is denied" and the bitcoind program was deleted from bitcoin/daemon dir. 
I check the error log and it shows the following:

```
tor: thread interrupt
opencon thread intrrupt
scheduler thread interrupt
torcontrol thread exit
addcon thread interrupt
msghand thread interrupt
net thread interrupt
Shutdown: In progress...
StopNode()
Shutdown: done
```

I'm not running Tor. Any ideas what change could have prompted this new error from the update?

Comment: Deleted sounds really weird. Can you check your virusscanner?see if it quarantined or deleted the file. Virus scanners are known for falsely labeling bitcoin as malware. But do double check that the files that you downloaded are correct by checking their hashes and such.

Comment: The messages about torcontrol are unrelated. 0.12 tries to contact your Tor node to create a hidden service if you have one, but there is no harm if that does not work.

Comment: Im running bitcoind with no problem atm, and I downloaded it yesterday so defintly the latest version.
So its probbaly a linux permission error.

Comment: Nothing in my sandbox, or quarantined by anti-virus. Spent all day at this, no luck getting it to work. Went right back to normal once I went back to version 11.2.  I guess I'll need to stick with an older version for now.  *confused*